# CKeditor: How to build a custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

I am trying to create a custom plugin for CKeditor following [this guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1). I created the files as indicated (myplugin.png, myplugin.js, plugin.js) and added

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = { 
    'default': { 
        'extraPlugins': ','.join( [ 'myplugin' ] ), 
        'allowedContent' : True,
    }
}
```

to the settings.

This is the content of my plugin.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'myplugin', {
    icons: 'myplugin',
    init: function( editor ) {
        // Plugin logic goes here...
        editor.addCommand( 'myplugin', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'mypluginDialog' ) );

        editor.ui.addButton( 'myplugin', {
            label: 'My Plugin',
            command: 'myplugin',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

Yet, the icon of the custom plugin still doesn't show. I can see in the browser's tools that the plugin.js file is retrieved. I made a test by removing the icon file and it didn't create any difference (no error message, no 404). I suppose then that the file is not even called or accessed. so the initialization does not even try to render the button.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to log before the errors in the `ckeditor.js` file, maybe that will give you more clues.

Comment: Something weird is that... I can't debug in the file. When I try to access this script (ckeditor.js) from Firebug, it tells: "No Javascript on this page

If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct)."

Comment: I found out the source of the problem. It was due to a cache file being server and thus the content was not exactly the one shown in my original post. With that fixed, the error does not show anymore and all seems to work.. except that the button for the plugin does not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer to the problem. It comes from the way CKEditor displays the toolbars. In the guide, the custom plugin is added to the "insert" group of the toolbars. However, this one will not be visible until it is explicitely set to be displayed.
Adding the extra plugin to the default configuration is not enough, the toolbar setting has to be specified properly (if for some reason, your platform doesn't default to null). In my case, with django-ckeditor, I had to add

```
'toolbar': None,
```

to the CKEDITOR_CONFIGS.